# Disabling the store page in prestashop

Tags: php, prestashop, prestashop-1.7

is it possible to turn off the store on prestashop? I am not interested in enabling maintenance mode. I need to leave all other subpages, eg "About the company", "contact". I need to disable the possibility of entering the product category and the product itself.
I understand this is a strange idea, but I was asked to do so.

Prestashop 1.7.5.0

Answer (score 0):

A possible way to do so would be to override main front controller, check the controller name
and redirect to a custom page if you have a match with unwanted controller (like "product" , "category" etc...